# Proper way to export dynamic module

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I have a NestJS application with the `CoreModule` which exports an collection of the core services to all other modules.
In core module i have dynamic module register `HttpModule`.
I won't to register this module twice for import and export so i do the following:

```
const httpModule = HttpModule.register({
    timeout: Configuration.requestTimeoutMilliseconds
});

@Module({
    imports: [httpModule],
    providers: [
        ...
    ],
    exports: [
        httpModule,
        ...
    ]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

When i start my app i see in `InstanceLoader` logs `HttpModule` dependencies registered twice:

[image]

What the proper way to export dynamic modules in general?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    HttpModule.register({
      timeout: Configuration.requestTimeoutMilliseconds,
    }),
  ],
  providers: [],
  exports: [HttpModule],
})
export class CoreModule {}
```

Makes sense to me because when you want to implement a dynamic module, you need to return module class as a module identifier in the module field.

There are examples of declaring dynamic modules on this page in documentation https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/dynamic-modules#module-configuration